# How to get Expression's Object.Value with Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I want to get the value of a list. My method like this:

```
 private void predicateTest(Expression<Func<bool>> predicate)
        {
            var body = predicate.Body;

            var binaryExpression = body as BinaryExpression;
            var binaryBody= binaryExpression ??    
                        Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, 
                        body, Expression.Constant(true));
            var left = binaryBody.Left;
        }
```

And my calling:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "doc", "exe", "jpg" };

predicateTest(() => list.Contains("sdf"));
```

And predicate.Body.Left value like following picture.
How to get value of list as programmatic in predicateTest method?

[image]

Comment: I think you'd want an [expression visitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. You can find examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks. I will research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following passes:

```
    private List<string> predicateTest(Expression<Func<bool>> predicate)
    {
        var body = predicate.Body;

        var binaryExpression = body as BinaryExpression;
        var binaryBody = binaryExpression ??
                    Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal,
                    body, Expression.Constant(true));
        var left = binaryBody.Left;

        return Expression.Lambda(((MethodCallExpression)left).Object).Compile().DynamicInvoke() as List<string>;
    }

    [Test]
    public void PredicateTest_ShouldFindList()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string> { "doc", "exe", "jpg" };
        var result = predicateTest(() => list.Contains("sdf"));
        Assert.That(list, Is.SameAs(result));
    }
```

Of course, if your expression is in even a little bit different format from what you've indicated, you'll get various exceptions. The ability to parse what you want out of an expression that may be in a variety of forms is one of the benefits of the visitor that Ed recommended.